# Free alternative to iMindMap 11 / Ayoa?

Tags: mind-mapping

I need a free alternative to iMindMap mind mapping software. I only want Mind Map feature according to Tony Buzan's book "Mind Mapping"; the features like Capture / Brainstorm / Time Map / Presentation / etc. are not that important.

The software would be used for the educational purposes, and would run within Windows XP 32-bit.